# How to make a grid of images with padding in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a grid that is 2 pictures in height and 3 pictures in length inside of the section div. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs2Y1.jpg) would be the optimal solution.
Underneath the picture would be a descriptive text that would be limited to the width of a single image. All these images and text would have a padding for each other. 
Here is the JSfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/278sem83/

***CSS***

```
body{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    background-color:#ff6600;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    padding:2px;
}

#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    height:350px;
    width:125px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}

#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#737373;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
}

#container {
    margin:auto;
    width:900px;
    text-align:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner_block {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    height:200px;
}

img {
    width: 350px;
}

.main_block{
    text-align:center;
    width:750px;

}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="container"><!---container--->
    <div id="header">
        <h1>JORDAS</h1>
    </div><!--header-->

    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a> <br>
        <a href="teltat.html">Teltat</a><br>
        <a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a><br>
        <a href="Yhteystiedot.html">Yhteistiedot</a><br>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <div class="main_block">
            <p> Tervetuloa Jordas Ab:n kotisivuille. Olemme...
        </div><!--mainblock-->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
    </div><!--footer-->
</div> <!--container-->
```

Comment: You still didn't post your "efforts" for this specific problem. You just gave a link to the website/fiddle that you created, but what did you attempt to accomplish the aforementioned layout.

Comment: I tried to make a div with same properties as in div inner_block, but without success. I cannot scale the pictures for some reason.

Comment: i removed the  img {
  width: 350px;
} but even after that i cant make the pictures smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Here some code that will get you started to get the layout you wanted:

```
<div class="main_block">

    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div> 

</div><!--mainblock-->
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 29%;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid blue;  
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfeLtafz/

Comment: this works in the JSfiddle but not in notepad++. I wonder what that could be. It works when pasted from aand to jsfiddle. but not when i run it in firefox.